# Specifying multiple RelativeSource.AncestorTypes

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

Is there a easy hack for doing the following?

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl OR Window}" Path="Tag" />
```

I simply want to bind to the top-level parent's Tag property, which could either be UserControl or Window. Note however that the distance from the current control to the parent is arbitrary, so I can't use `AncestorLevel`.

Comment: There's no reason to list tags in your question titles. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for the discussion of why it's not needed.

Comment: Also, similar to what stukselbax wrote in response to your [other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) you could probably solve this with a markup extension, or with some value converter. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Patrick: Thanks for the tags usage advice. That makes perfect sense. As for stukselbax's answer (your may want to correct the link in your comment), that is quite complicated for me at this point. As you see below in Phil's answer, the solution was far more simple.

Comment: @Patrick: Although Phil's answer works best for this quesetion in general, I later found out that stukselbax's answer actually worked better in my specific case. Thanks for pushing me back to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if it's a hack you want :)

```
public partial class MainWindow : ITopLevel
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Tag = "I'm at the top";
    }
}

public interface ITopLevel
{
    // optionally specify Tag in the interface, it will work either way
    object Tag { get; set; }
}

<Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
            FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Demo:ITopLevel}}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: hmmm that's an interesting approach! Currently I approach this problem by having a MainWindowViewModel with the stuff I need on it. I either use a FindAncestor Window bind in xaml or pass the MainWindowViewModel to the child using IoC and access what I need that way.

Comment: @Phil: Perfect. Wonder why in the world I didn't come up with that simple idea.

Comment: That's not a hack. That's clever utilization of language's capabilities. Like it!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `MultiBinding` instead of `Binding` for this, and then make a simple `IMultiValueConverter` that finds the first item in "values" that isn't null (or `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, which tends to pop up when working with the Visual Tree.

It's a less hacky way to do this, and works perfectly for me.